# Resource not found java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, oracle

I tried to run the sample program from docs.oracle.com .

TrayIconDemo.java

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 

package misc;  
/*
 * TrayIconDemo.java
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TrayIconDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //adding TrayIcon.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Check the SystemTray support
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
            return;
        }
        final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
        final TrayIcon trayIcon =
                new TrayIcon(createImage("images/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
        final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        // Create a popup menu components
        MenuItem aboutItem = new MenuItem("About");
        CheckboxMenuItem cb1 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set auto size");
        CheckboxMenuItem cb2 = new CheckboxMenuItem("Set tooltip");
        Menu displayMenu = new Menu("Display");
        MenuItem errorItem = new MenuItem("Error");
        MenuItem warningItem = new MenuItem("Warning");
        MenuItem infoItem = new MenuItem("Info");
        MenuItem noneItem = new MenuItem("None");
        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

        //Add components to popup menu
        popup.add(aboutItem);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add(cb1);
        popup.add(cb2);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add(displayMenu);
        displayMenu.add(errorItem);
        displayMenu.add(warningItem);
        displayMenu.add(infoItem);
        displayMenu.add(noneItem);
        popup.add(exitItem);

        trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
            return;
        }

        trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This dialog box is run from System Tray");
            }
        });

        aboutItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This dialog box is run from the About menu item");
            }
        });

        cb1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                int cb1Id = e.getStateChange();
                if (cb1Id == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
                } else {
                    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(false);
                }
            }
        });

        cb2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                int cb2Id = e.getStateChange();
                if (cb2Id == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    trayIcon.setToolTip("Sun TrayIcon");
                } else {
                    trayIcon.setToolTip(null);
                }
            }
        });

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MenuItem item = (MenuItem)e.getSource();
                //TrayIcon.MessageType type = null;
                System.out.println(item.getLabel());
                if ("Error".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                    //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR;
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is an error message", TrayIcon.MessageType.ERROR);

                } else if ("Warning".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                    //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING;
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is a warning message", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);

                } else if ("Info".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                    //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO;
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is an info message", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);

                } else if ("None".equals(item.getLabel())) {
                    //type = TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE;
                    trayIcon.displayMessage("Sun TrayIcon Demo",
                            "This is an ordinary message", TrayIcon.MessageType.NONE);
                }
            }
        };

        errorItem.addActionListener(listener);
        warningItem.addActionListener(listener);
        infoItem.addActionListener(listener);
        noneItem.addActionListener(listener);

        exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tray.remove(trayIcon);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    //Obtain the image URL
    protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
        URL imageURL = TrayIconDemo.class.getResource(path);

        if (imageURL == null) {
            System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
            return null;
        } else {
            return (new ImageIcon(imageURL, description)).getImage();
        }
    }
}
```

and that program need bulb.gif file , here the link for bulb.gif https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/TrayIconDemoProject/src/misc/images/bulb.gif. i already create images folder contained bulb.gif. but why everytime i run the program it say

```
    Resource not found: images/bulb.gif
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: creating TrayIcon with null Image
    at java.awt.TrayIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at TrayIconDemo.createAndShowGUI(TrayIconDemo.java:76)
    at TrayIconDemo.access$0(TrayIconDemo.java:68)
    at TrayIconDemo$1.run(TrayIconDemo.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Im using windows 7 64 bit

i think the problem from here :

```
 final TrayIcon trayIcon =
            new TrayIcon(createImage("images/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
```

here my project structure
https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7491/15300162233_cdda5e541d_o.png

**The solution is**
1. place your .java file in default package/ without any package
2. then you should create images folder inside src folder and put the bulb.gif in there, so you can access it by type images/bulb.gif 
thanks to jitesh

Comment: Try giving absolute path of gif file in argument.

Comment: @KaustubhMallik /azura/images/bulb.gif you mean this one? or this one C:\Users\azura\workspace_intermediate_java_third\azura\images\bulb.gif?

Comment: I mean the second one i.e. C:\Users\azura\workspace_intermediate_java_third\azura\images\bulb.gif. It should work.

Comment: @KaustubhMallik i cant put C:\Users\azura\workspace_intermediate_java_third\azura\images\bulb.gif directly it say invalid escape sequence so i edit become like this C:\\Users\\azura\\workspace_intermediate_java_third\\azura\\images\\bulb.gif but it still showing Resource not found: C:\Users\azura\workspace_intermediate_java_third\azura\images\bulb.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error line is expecting image to be inside images folder relative to the folder from where eclipse is running this program.

```
final TrayIcon trayIcon =
        new TrayIcon(createImage("images/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
```

Check where eclipse is creating classes. You can find that out by looking at your project properties.
Create images folder inside that directory and copy image file.

One more solution(not so pretty though)will be to change the function call to :-

```
    final TrayIcon trayIcon =
        new TrayIcon(createImage("C:\\Users\\azura\\workspace_intermediate_java_third\\azura\\images\\bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
```

Comment: i create another class to check my path,static Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\azura\\workspace_intermediate_java_third\\azura\\images\\bulb.gif"); if(path != null){
   System.out.println("path exists");
   System.out.println(path.toString());
   System.out.println(path.getFileName());
  } it showing path exists
C:\Users\azura\workspace_intermediate_java_third\azura\images\bulb.gif
bulb.gif

Comment: That is very weird. Can you try the first solution that I mentioned in my answer - Create images folder in the directory that eclipse is placing class files into and copy the gif file there?

Comment: wow thanks man!, my mistake is i create images folder outside src folder ^^